# How to determine if my mail server is configured correctly?

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, smtp, dovecot, ptr-record

Does anyone know of an online service (similar to the ones that tell you if a site is up or down) that can connect to a specified mail server and perform checks to see if it is configured correctly?

If not, does anyone know exactly what these checks should be? (https://www.nearlyfreespeech.net/about/email gives an interesting stance, but looks to be not very specific)

The specific mail server I'm trying to see if it is configured properly is mx.adammw111.co.cc , but I'd rather find a automatic checker *outside* my own network than do many manual checks.

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe you can use spamassassin? Make it verbose, enable many tests, and see what you can fix.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried http://mxtoolbox.com it can check to see if you are blacklisted and you DNS records are correct, but doesn't really tell you if your configuration is correct.

Comment: +1 - MXtoolbox will also perform an open relay test for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.intodns.com.

This service produces quite a comprehensive report, excellent layout with detailed information about every item that has been tested.

Hope this helps.

Comment: These are strictly DNS tests.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one end-all be-all of mail configuration testing, because no one aside from yourself knows how you want your server configured.

There are tests, as other people have suggested, which allow you to test very specific conditions that frequently cause problems for mail administrators. Another such is the abuse.net test for open relays: http://www.abuse.net/relay.html

In the end, verify that you can send mail to your domain by using an external mail server (such as gmail or yahoo), that you can receive the mail that you sent, and that when you reply to the mail, your external account receives the reply.

After you have basic functionality down, test again as you change the configuration.

Answer (score -1):

[Found this tool](http://www.allaboutspam.com/email-server-test/) in a ServerFault comment. Note: the comment was self-promotional; I'll let you determine how legit this is.